# Weird problem: can not connect network until a terminal is opened in Live system

Tags: networking, command-line, server, bashrc

Live system based on ubuntu server 12.04.2 with manual installed X and openbox.
`startx` is in a shell script which is called in `/etc/rc.local` with `su -l root -c /scriptsFolder/script.sh`

A program is opened in openbox autostart config file and it can not connect to a server in LAN.

Once opened a terminal in openbox, the network goes well and the program can connect to the server.

Or, if pinged from other computer, a few seconds later the network goes well.

Really weird problem, could somebody tell me what **open a terminal**  did to make the network goes?

I've already checked bashrc but found nothing of value.

---

Seems that **open a terminal** influence only live system

I installed the live system into disk and **open a terminal** does not get the network goes well anymore, the only way to make the net well is to ping or be pinged.

So I updated the question to "what does **open a terminal** do in Live System that enables the network".

It's confusing... sorry for my bad English.

Really need help.